# Creating a 2d magnet simulator

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I need to create a "simple" magnet simulator, unfortunetely I have little to no physics knowledge.

The best way to describe my idea is, imagine a hockey table. There's a disk and I need to throw it around. So far no problems, I just have to calculate the disk acceleration and position along the time based on an initial force.

Now, let's suppose it's a magnetic disk and I want some fixed magnetic disks around the table. Now I want to throw the disk around the table again, but it have to have it's route modified when it goes near another disk(either by being repelled or attracted).

I have been looking for a few hours but I can't wrap my head around these formulas and how to put them together. Can someone please enlighten me on how would I go about solving this problem?

Comment: Just download the free [`FEMM`](http://www.femm.info/wiki/HomePage) software. It does magnetic simulation.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to simulate *electrostatic* charges for attraction and repulsion. See a simple simulation I made using JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/UbP7g/4/. Feel free to play around with the code and try changing some of the variables (such as the masses and charges of the particles).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to play around on this industry page http://www.kjmagnetics.com/calculator.asp?calcType=disc

They have a number of shapes where you can enter sizes and see how the force varies with distance.  Carlos Martin has a very nice page, but the forces I think are all based on a inverse square law of repulsion.

Answer (score 1):

Each magnet creates magnetic field around it.

Monopole creates field like this:

$E = k \frac{q}{r^2}$

where $q$ is monopole "charge", $k$ is a constant and $r$ is the distance from monopole.

Real magnets are dipoles, i.e. they consists of two opposite monopoles (opposite $q$)

The field creates a `force` on any object that can feel it.

The force is given by formula

$F = Eq_2$

where $q_2$ is the charge of receiving object.

You can set all charges as $+1$ or $-1$ and select $q$ to tune the level of magnetism.

Any force (not only electromagnetic) is a momentum growth.

$F=\frac{dp}{dt}$

So, if you have force $F$ and time quantum $dt$ you can calculate $dp=Fdt$ the amount of momentum, received by the body from the field.

Your task has complexity: being dipoles, magnets receive momentum by parts. So, in some cases they can start rotating or apply rotation to other objects.

This is separate task, ask it separately: how to model forces on constrained rigid bodies.

P.S. Forgot to say that all of force, field and momentum are vectors, i.e. directed values.